# React Developer Tool wrong check latest version

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

My project is using Reactjs for FE. I updated latest version "16.12.0" and build successfully. But React Developer tool still show "This page is using an outdated version of React. "

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "isomorphic",
  "version": "2.9.4",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "antd": "^3.25.3",
  "antd-local-icon": "^0.1.3",
  "apexcharts": "^3.10.1",
  "auth0-lock": "^11.18.1",
  "aws-amplify": "^1.2.4",
  "aws-amplify-react": "^2.5.4",
  "aws-appsync": "^1.8.1",
  "aws-appsync-react": "^1.2.9",
  "aws-sdk": "^2.580.0",
  "canvasjs": "^1.8.1",
  "card-react": "^1.2.7",
  "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
  "classnames": "^2.2.5",
  "clone": "^2.1.2",
  "cryptr": "^4.0.2",
  "d3-shape": "^1.3.7",
  "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
  "enzyme-react-intl": "^1.4.8",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "firebase": "^5.11.1",
  "fixed-data-table-2": "^0.8.28",
  "frappe-charts": "^0.0.8",
  "globalize": "^1.4.2",
  "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
  "history": "^4.10.1",
  "immutable": "^3.8.1",
  "immutable-devtools": "^0.0.7",
  "js-info-bubble": "git+https://github.com/RedQ/js-info-bubble.git",
  "js-rich-marker": "^1.1.2",
  "lodash": "^4.17.15",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
  "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
  "polished": "^1.7.0",
  "postcss-inline-rtl": "^0.9.8",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "ramda": "^0.25.0",
  "react": "^16.12.0",
  "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.5.2",
  "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.3",
  "react-apollo": "^2.5.8",
  "react-big-calendar": "^0.17.0",
  "react-canvas-js": "^1.0.1",
  "react-chartjs-2": "^2.8.0",
  "react-codemirror": "^1.0.0",
  "react-count-down": "^1.2.1",
  "react-csv-reader": "^0.3.2",
  "react-dates": "12.2.4",
  "react-dnd": "^2.3.0",
  "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.3.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  "react-drawer": "^1.2.5",
  "react-dropzone-component": "^3.0.0",
  "react-element-resize": "^0.2.3",
  "react-error-overlay": "^1.0.10",
  "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.0.0",
  "react-flip-move": "^2.9.2",
  "react-google-charts": "^1.6.0",
  "react-grid-layout": "^0.16.2",
  "react-highlight-words": "^0.16.0",
  "react-instantsearch": "^4.0.7",
  "react-intl": "^2.9.0",
  "react-ladda": "^5.0.6",
  "react-lex": "^1.2.1",
  "react-motion-drawer": "^2.1.7",
  "react-pdf": "^4.1.0",
  "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.0",
  "react-placeholder": "^2.0.0",
  "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
  "react-rectangle-selection": "^1.0.4",
  "react-redux": "^5.1.2",
  "react-router": "^4.1.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.1.0",
  "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
  "react-scripts": "2.1.0",
  "react-selectable": "^2.0.2",
  "react-sidebar": "^2.3.2",
  "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^8.0.6",
  "react-speech-recognition": "^1.1.0",
  "react-tag-input": "^4.7.2",
  "react-tags": "^0.2.2",
  "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0",
  "react-throttle": "^0.3.0",
  "react-trend": "^1.2.5",
  "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
  "react-window-size-listener": "^1.5.4",
  "react-youtube": "^7.9.0",
  "recharts": "^1.8.5",
  "redux": "^3.6.0",
  "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
  "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
  "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0",
  "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
  "redux-saga-firebase": "0.10.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  "reselect": "^3.0.0",
  "rheostat": "^2.1.1",
  "rich-marker": "^0.0.1",
  "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.5.0",
  "sort-json-array": "^0.1.7",
  "styled-components": "^2.2.1",
  "styled-theme": "^0.3.3",
  "uppy": "0.18.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "babel-plugin-ramda": "^1.5.0",
   "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
   "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
  "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.3",
  "google-maps-react": "^1.1.0",
  "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
  "leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.12",
  "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.1",
  "react-app-rewired": "1.6.2",
  "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=8192 build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"browserslist": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not ie <= 11",
  "not op_mini all"
 ]
}
```

Which package I need update to React Developer tool show is "This page is using the production build of React" ?

Comment: have you make a new BUILD? if not you are using the last build with the old version

Comment: Yes, I have. After I change version in package.json I ran "npm install" then "npm run build"

Comment: I dunno, maybe you should check how `react-app-rewired` make a build, as you are not using react-scripts

Comment: I checked and found problem. It is "auth0-lock". But I don't know how to fix